# How do I get the $_POST method to work on subdomain with CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, post

As my title says, the $ _POST method won't work correctly on my CodeIgniter installation. The values do not follow through when posting a form.

**Strange thing 1:**
It works great on my "non-subdomain" site that has the **exact same codes**.

**Strange thing 2:**
It works when adding "/index.php/" in the path. But still, I haven't done that on my other site. But I use .htaccess on both sites, and even those files look exactly like. Here is the code:

```
#php_value default_charset UTF-8

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|img|swf|xml|robots\.txt|css|js|favicon.ico|robots.txt|404.html)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

So, how do I get the form post working correctly on a CodeIgniter installation on a subdomain?

Comment: when you say the values `do not follow through`, is this confirmed with some POST data analysis, such as viewing the posted data with Firebug?

If the data is actually being sent properly, then next look at the receiving file.

Comment: @Leon Stafford: I have now looked in Google Chrome Developer Tool. Under the "Network" section, "Form data". There are actually correct values ​​there. So what could be wrong then? **Edit:** Worth to notice too is the following information from Network data: _Request Method:POST
Status Code:404 Not Found_.

Comment: have you tried using codeigniter library instead of $_POST, i.e $this->input->post(); for all data, or $this->input->post('field_name'); for specific data? also, are you sure you are not redirecting before using/printing/echoing the fields

Comment: What OS is your server and do you have root access to it? It's potentially an issue with the `apache2/sites-available/default` file.

Comment: @death_relic: Yes I have tried codeigniter library. But as I said, it works perfectly on my other site, that is on the same server and exactly the same codes. That's why I feel like it's something to do with the subdomain.

Comment: @Jordan Arseno: No, I don't have access to server settings.

Comment: my guess is that your server is not configured to allow reading of .htaccess inside the directory that stores your subdomain, only the generic `/www` directory. Contact your host, or hunt around your administrative panel.

Comment: if your code is exactly the same, then it does point to a server issue. there are many ways to setup a subdomain. sometimes the document root is setup as a subfolder of the main domain, which could explain the fact that you need the index.php in and htaccess not working as intended.

try running this command from the root of both sites and output here what is returned:

`http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php`

Answer (score 1):

What is your base url set to?

Chances are whats happening is when someone visits `subdomain.mysite.com` the form is posting to `mysite.com` without the subdomain.

Try this (and you can most likely get rid of all those extra rewrite rules you have):

`$config['base_url']    = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/site-folder-if-any/';`

I have used this successfully while sending $_POST data with subdomains

This will also make sure that all links generated by `site_url(), form_open(), etc.` have the correct url.